# Building a LoRa Gateway to capture all spreading factors and all bandwidths on Raspberry PI

Tags: pi-4, pi-3b+

As the title suggests, I have a substantial task at hand, so I'm unsure if I'll be able to cover everything in this message. However, I'll attempt to provide links to related questions if needed. I want to preface by acknowledging that what I'm attempting might not be feasible, as I've only come across two existing products in the market for this particular purpose, and only one of them demonstrated partial functionality.

So, I am building a LoRa Gateway that dose NOT connect to TTN, but a personal server side application that I developed. So I don't need the TTN authentification nonsense. I've been able to build something with SX127x in python that is able to receive messages from one or many nodes and forward those messages to the server, but only on one specific bandwidth(eg: 125kHz) and one spreading factor.

What am I aiming for?

1. A reliable gateway that can receive data from all bandwidths from 65kHz to 500kHz, all spreding factors from 7 to 12 and all coding rates from 4/5 to 4/8.
2. A way to receive and transmit data at the same time(I've been thinging to place a secound LoRa module on the raspberry and controll it spearately)
3. A setup/standard to use: I've been using python and it has been more like hit and miss. There are a lot of libraries for this and I've stuck with SX127x because it is the only one that worked. If there is a standar lib that covers all or most of the transceivers, please let me know. It does not have to be in python, but I would like a guide for it or documentation.

What I've been using till now:

I've been using a Raspberry PI 3B+/4 with Raspbian(latest version) python 3 and an RFM95 LoRa module.

As for the comertial solutions that I've been trying:

I've purchased a RAK5146 and I've successfully installed the application and the gateway-config commands for it. The ChirpStack application is running successfully on port 8080, but I've been completly unsuccessfull in linking it to my personal application. I've been searching the internet for a guide and documentation, but I'm stuck in how to connect to their solutions, not a private server application. If there is someone who did more research on this matter, I would appreciate a heads up. The RAK5146 is basically what I've been describing above, but I'm still searching for alternatives since it's quite expensive.

Question: Is there an opensource LoRa concentrator that can be programmed by hand and fulfilles all those criterias? Or at least most of them. It does not need to be a comercial solution. I can order the parts directy to the manufacture.

PS: If this is not the right subdivision of stack exchange for these kind of questions, I  apologize and please refer me to the right one. Thanks!

Comment: you forgot to ask a question ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post